# How do I send parameter from a page in loader using Ext JS or Ext.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I have a window component that using loader configuration like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    id: 'window1',
    title: 'Lookup Master Soal',
    height: 500,
    width: 800,
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    loader: {
        url: 'http://mydomain.com:34573/CBC/Pertanyaan/MasterSoal/Default.aspx?lookup=true',
        renderer: 'frame',
        autoLoad: true,
        scripts: true,
        loadMask: {
            showMask: true
        }
    }
}).show();
```

I have some javascript code in http://mydomain.com:34573/CBC/Pertanyaan/MasterSoal/Default.aspx, and I want to send some parameter to the window. I have no idea to do this. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a Window from its iframe page (loaded via its Loader) in JavaScript via the "parentAutoLoadControl" reference.

Comment: I don't mean I want to send a value via query string from window's loader to URL, rather I want send back a value to window component.

Comment: You can access a Window from its iframe page in JavaScript via the "parentAutoLoadControl" reference.

Comment: that's exactly what I mean. Thank you :)